# Apache Rewrite - hosted images exception

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I use...

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} . 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://([^.]+\.)?graphium\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(googlebot–image|msnbot|psbot|yahoo–mmcrawler) [NC]
RewriteRule \.(bmp|gif|jpe?g|png)$ /images/hotlink.$1 [L]
```

...in my httpd.conf to stop people linking directly to any images on my site. Mostly, it has always, does and, I trust, always will, Just Work.

But I want to amend the rules to allow for a named directory to contain linkable images. Just the one directory (lets call it /public_html/pictures) - but I can't see how to amend my ruleset to allow this.

Any suggestions, anyone?

Comment: Did you try to `RewriteEngine off` inside a Directory container?

Answer (score 0):

If you put `RewriteEngine off` inside a container for that URI, it should override your conditional rewrite rules in the global scope.  For example:

```
<Directory /public_html/pictures>
RewriteEngine off
</Directory>
```

should produce the desired result.

You can also use `Location` instead of `Directory` -- or you could place `RewriteEngine off` inside a `.htaccess` file and place that in the desired subdirectory.

Please let me know if this works for you.